# Exporting image collection to asset

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying to export an image collection of model results as an asset in GEE but I get the error message:

> Error: Unable to export features with unbounded geometry.

The images in the collection are calculated from the GDDP dataset and have the same global footprint as the source data. I have tried filtering the collection by bounds but still get the same message. Following is a code that replicates my problem:

```
var GDDP = ee.ImageCollection('NASA/NEX-GDDP').filterDate('2002-01-01')
Export.table.toAsset(GDDP, 'GDDP', 'GDDP')
```

Comment: I can run your sample code without any issues. Although it seems weird that `GDDP` is an Image Collection, while you're calling the function to export table.

Comment: @Kevin It is very strange that the sample code runs for you but not for me. The Export.table function is used to export Feature Collections in GEE and as far as I understand Image Collections are Feature Collections that contain images.

Comment: Is there a solution to this? I am having the same problem. Is it even possible to export an image collection to asset?

Answer (score 0):

You can't export a whole ImageCollection to an asset in one go.  You'd have to export each image independently into a newly created collection.