# Export ImageCollection to an Asset - Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have the same difficulty in exporting an ImageCollection to an asset in Google Earth Engine.

This align with the previous question on this forum.
[Exporting image collection to asset](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/330616/exporting-image-collection-to-asset?newreg=7dc5b3f9b9cb40d2996a2aa621ade8de)

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site.  Please check out our short [tour] to learn about our focussed Q&A format.  Please don't re-ask questions, even if they were first asked many years ago; these are your [Options when question is duplicate of one with no/inadequate/old answers](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4010).

Comment: Thanks.. I will share the question.

Comment: Can I share the same question?

Comment: As far as I know you can choose to use the share button on any question.

Comment: I can only copy the code... Can I make it reappear as a question in the forum?

Comment: This is not a forum; it is a focused Q&A site, and the same question can only be asked once on it.  Please take the [Tour] so that you can come up to speed on it quicker.